# JPQL and Inheritance

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Lets supose that I have 3 abstract super classes: `SuperA`, `SuperB` and `SuperC`.
Lets supose that each of theses super classes had a lot of more specific implementations, and all the superclasses are annotated with `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`.

More specific:

- `Aa` <- `SuperA` and has a List of `SuperB` (the `bbs` property);
- `Bb` <- `SuperB` and has a List of `SuperC` (the `ccs` property);
- `Cc` <- `SuperC` and has a `foo` property.

Then, when I try a query like the following, I got an error saying that it could not find the property `foo` in the type `SuperC`. `Bb` has a list of the abstract type, and I can't change that. So, I do not know how to make the query works.

```
select a from Aa a left outer join a.bbs b where b.ccs.foo = :foo
```

Any tip will help. Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:

BTW: the exception:

`org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'cc3_1_.foo' in 'where clause'`

---

Edit 2:

I look for JPA docs, and found [something](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA/QueryDownCast) that could work, if I'm not using Hibernate.

---

Edit 3:

I change it to use two SQL's. First, I find the id of the C based on the `foo` property, then I just do the query comparing with the id.

The problem here, is that I have to do 2 SQL's for every time I want this... but, at least it works.

Comment: Its smells like a bug of your ORM framework, just because you want access an property/field in 'Cc' table and not in 'SuperC'. Programaticaly you should make and explicit cast to SuperC.foo ....

Comment: One question, it's a generated query or builded manually ?

Comment: Based on this post [link]http://www.java.net/node/668740[/link], you can be use descendant classes instead your super classes on your mappings... `class Aa { private List<Cc> ccs; ....`

Comment: that should work.. but I don't really want to do that in that way... I really need the abstract list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more join for the list of Cc's then it should be fine:

```
select a from Aa a left outer join a.bbs b join b.ccs c where c.foo = :foo
```

as ccs is a list you can't "dereference" it's property this way, if you could you wouldn't need joins, you could simply write: `a.bbs.ccs.foo` **but this is not the case** so you need to join the lists as I wrote above.